# undefined method `each' for String when using https

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

In my application staging environment there is an error when I try to access a page over https, the webpage is correctly working with http. The error I get is :

```
 undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000009371f28>
```

The place where it fails is on in th gem rack on the line:

```
body.each { |part| parts << part }
```

in

```
def digest_body(body)
    parts = []
    body.each { |part| parts << part }
    string_body = parts.join
    digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(string_body) unless string_body.empty?
    [digest, parts]
end
```

It seems that he can't handle the body that is passed. I inspected the body and it is a string with all the html code of my page in it. The data type of this parameter should be an array.

```
 "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class='no-js' lang='fr' xml:lang='fr'>\n<head>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>\n<meta content='width=device-width' name='viewport'>\n<title>Bienvenue sur Zurban Culture | Admin Panel | Zurban Culture</title>\n<meta content=\"authenticity_token\" name=\"csrf-param\" />\n<meta content=\"fEVrJPyUwdf4FZ2GSWW/p01SrByXlJpq+xSbAXOkxBg=\" name=\"csrf-token\" />\n<!--[if lt IE 9]>\n<script src='http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>\n<![endif]-->\n<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n<link href=\"/assets/admin/admin-6033541466a41863e188a9fa9e0ea9bd.css\" media=\"screen\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<link href=\"/assets/admin/print-088f5bc50dba980c42676157c724ed0a.css\" media=\"print\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n\n<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>\n\n<link href='/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon'>\n</head>\n<body data-offset='50' data-spy='scroll' id='admin_show'>\n<h1 class='hidden print'>\nZurban Culture\n</h1>\n<div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top noPrint'>\n<div class='navbar-inner'>\n<div class='container-fluid'>\n<a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'>\n<span class='icon-bar'></span>\n<span class='icon-bar'></span>\n<span class='icon-bar'></span>\n</a>\n<a class='brand' href='/admin'>Zurban Culture</a>\n<div class='nav-collapse'>\n<ul class='nav' id='tabbedInterface'>\n<li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Produits<b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/products\">Tous produits (4064)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/products/incomplete\">Brouillons (156)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/products/deleted\">Effacés (274)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/purchases\">Bons</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/product_types\">Familles (24)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/products/maintenance\">Maintenance</a></li>\n</ul>\n</li><li class=\"brands_tab\"><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/brands\">Marques</a></li>\n<li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Ventes & Marketing<b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/sales\">En vente (3905)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/sales/incomplete\">Brouillons (142)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/sales/new\">Planning (0)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/sales/planned\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.menu.sales.planned\">Planned</span></a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/discounts\">Codes promotionnels (27)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/sales/dashboard\">Page d&#x27;accueil</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/campaigns\">Collections</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/gift_cards/active_not_used\">Chèques cadeaux</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/cheques\">Chèques</a></li>\n</ul>\n</li><li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Commandes<b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/pending\">En attente (0)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/fraud_review\">A vérifier (3)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/paid\">Payées (7)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/processing\">Traitement (0)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/shipped\">Envoyées (307)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/completed\">Complètée (9205)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/unavailable_hold\">Indisponible (1)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/cancelled\">Annulées (8736)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/orders/fraud\">Fraudes (12)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/order_transactions\">Tentatives de paiements</a></li>\n</ul>\n</li><li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Retours<b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/returns/pending\">En attente (77)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/returns/received\">Réceptionné (23)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/returns/completed\">Remboursé (1115)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/returns/cancelled\">Procédure annulée (4)</a></li>\n</ul>\n</li><li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Avis <b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/reviews/needs_approvement\">À approuver (0)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/reviews/approved\">Approuvés (3)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/reviews/refused\">Refusés (0)</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/reviews/deleted\">Effacés (0)</a></li>\n</ul>\n</li><li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Utilisateurs<b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/users\">Utilisateurs</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/users/deleted\">Utilisateurs effacés</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/invitations\">Invitations</a></li>\n</ul>\n</li><li class=\"help_sections_tab\"><a href=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin/help_sections\">Sections d&#x27;aide</a></li>\n<li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"><img alt=\"Icon_stats\" src=\"/assets/admin/icon_stats-3905dbfb6e4ba900e54d7c49d67f5c49.png\" /><b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.overview\">Overview</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/products\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.products\">Products</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/orders\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.orders\">Orders</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/returns\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.returns\">Returns</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/users\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.users\">Users</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/sales_report\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.sales_report\">Sales Report</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/stock_by_brand\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.stock_report\">Stock Report</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/purchases\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.purchase_report\">Purchase Report</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/statistics/general\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.sales_history\">Sales History</span></a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/favorites\"><span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: fr.admin.submenu.favorites\">Favorites</span></a>\n</li>\n</ul>\n</li></ul>\n\n<ul class='nav pull-right'>\n<li class='searchbox'>\n<form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/admin/search\" class=\"navbar-search pull-right\" method=\"get\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /></div>\n<input class=\"search-query span2\" id=\"query\" name=\"query\" size=\"20\" type=\"text\" value=\"Rechercher\" />\n\n</form>\n\n</li>\n<li class='dropdown'>\n<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>\n<i class='icon-user icon-white'></i>\n</a>\n<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n<li>\n<a href=\"/\">Zurban Culture</a>\n</li>\n<li>\n<a href=\"/logout\">Déconnexion</a>\n</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class='container-fluid noPrint'>\n<div class='subnav'>\n<ul class='nav nav-pills'>\n<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"/admin\">Statistique rapides</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/admin/maintenances\">Logs</a></li>\n</ul>\n\n</div>\n<div class='notices_wrapper noPrint'>\n<div class='row-fluid'>\n<div class='span12'>\n\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class='container-fluid'>\n<div class='row-fluid'>\n<div class='span12'>\n<div class=\"page-header\">\n <h1>Bienvenue sur Zurban Culture</h1> \n</div>\n\n\n <form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"https://beta.jeansattitude.fr/admin\" class=\"well\" method=\"get\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /></div>\n <input class=\"datepicker onChangeSubmit\" id=\"start_date\" length=\"8\" name=\"start_date\" placeholder=\"Start Date\" type=\"text\" value=\"2013-04-01\" />\n <input class=\"datepicker onChangeSubmit\" id=\"end_date\" length=\"8\" name=\"end_date\" placeholder=\"End Date\" type=\"text\" value=\"2013-04-23\" />\n <input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn\">\n </form>\n <div class=\"row-fluid\">\n <div class=\"section dashboard span6\" id=\"orders_section\">\n <div class=\"well\">\n <h2 class=\"sectionHeader\">Montant des ventes cumulés</h2>\n <div id=\"ordersChart\" class=\"graph\" style=\"width: 95%; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0\"></div>\n </div>\n </div>\n <div class=\"section dashboard span6\" id=\"revenue_section\">\n <div class=\"well\">\n <h2 class=\"sectionHeader\">Montant des ventes</h2>\n <div id=\"revenueChart\" class=\"graph\" style=\"width: 95%; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0\"></div>\n </div>\n </div>\n </div>\n\n <div class=\"row-fluid\">\n <div class=\"section dashboard span6\" id=\"orders_shipped_section\">\n <div class=\"well\">\n <h2 class=\"sectionHeader\">Commandes Expédiées</h2>\n <div id=\"shippedOrdersChart\" class=\"graph\" style=\"width: 95%; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0\"></div>\n </div>\n </div>\n\n <div class=\"section dashboard span6\" id=\"users_section\">\n <div class=\"well\">\n <h2 class=\"sectionHeader\">Nouveaux utilisateurs confirmés</h2>\n <div id=\"usersChart\" class=\"graph\" style=\"width: 95%; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0\"></div>\n </div>\n </div>\n </div>\n\n\n <div id=\"revenueChart\"></div>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar rgviz_revenueChart = null;\nvar rgviz_revenueChart_data = null;\nfunction rgviz_draw_revenueChart() {\n var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/orders/datasource');\n var q = 'select toDate(`paid_at`), `old_members`, `new_members` where ((`state` = \"paid\" or `state` = \"processing\" or `state` = \"shipped\" or `state` = \"completed\") and `paid_at` >= \"2013-04-01\" and `paid_at` <= \"2013-04-24\") group by toDate(`paid_at`) order by toDate(`paid_at`) asc label toDate(`paid_at`) \\'Date\\', `old_members` \\'Ventes Anciens Utilisateurs\\', `new_members` \\'Ventes Nouveaux Utilisateurs\\'';\n query.setQuery(q);\n query.send(function(response) {\n rgviz_revenueChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('revenueChart'));\n rgviz_revenueChart_data = response.getDataTable();\n rgviz_revenueChart_options = {\"is3D\":true,\"width\":\"100%\",\"height\":\"80%\",\"legend\":{\"position\":\"bottom\",\"textStyle\":{\"fontSize\":12}},\"chartArea\":{\"left\":70,\"top\":30,\"width\":\"85%\",\"height\":\"75%\"},\"isStacked\":true};\n rgviz_revenueChart.draw(rgviz_revenueChart_data, rgviz_revenueChart_options);\n});\n}\ngoogle.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {'packages':['corechart']});\ngoogle.setOnLoadCallback(rgviz_draw_revenueChart);\n</script>\n\n\n <div id=\"ordersChart\"></div>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar rgviz_ordersChart = null;\nvar rgviz_ordersChart_data = null;\nfunction rgviz_draw_ordersChart() {\n var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/orders/datasource');\n var q = 'select toDate(`paid_at`), sum(`total`) where ((`state` = \"paid\" or `state` = \"processing\" or `state` = \"shipped\" or `state` = \"completed\") and `paid_at` >= \"2013-04-01\" and `paid_at` <= \"2013-04-24\") group by toDate(`paid_at`) order by toDate(`paid_at`) asc label toDate(`paid_at`) \\'Date\\', sum(`total`) \\'Montant Ventes\\'';\n query.setQuery(q);\n query.send(function(response) {\n rgviz_ordersChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('ordersChart'));\n rgviz_ordersChart_data = response.getDataTable();\n rgviz_ordersChart_options = {\"is3D\":true,\"width\":\"100%\",\"height\":\"80%\",\"legend\":\"none\",\"chartArea\":{\"left\":70,\"top\":30,\"width\":\"85%\",\"height\":\"75%\"}};\n rgviz_ordersChart.draw(rgviz_ordersChart_data, rgviz_ordersChart_options);\n});\n}\ngoogle.setOnLoadCallback(rgviz_draw_ordersChart);\n</script>\n\n <div id=\"shippedOrdersChart\"></div>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar rgviz_shippedOrdersChart = null;\nvar rgviz_shippedOrdersChart_data = null;\nfunction rgviz_draw_shippedOrdersChart() {\n var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/orders/datasource');\n var q = 'select toDate(`shipped_at`), count(`id`) where ((`state` = \"paid\" or `state` = \"processing\" or `state` = \"shipped\" or `state` = \"completed\") and `shipped_at` >= \"2013-04-01\" and `paid_at` <= \"2013-04-24\") group by toDate(`shipped_at`) order by toDate(`shipped_at`) asc label toDate(`shipped_at`) \\'Date\\', count(`id`) \\'Commandes Expédiées\\'';\n query.setQuery(q);\n query.send(function(response) {\n rgviz_shippedOrdersChart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('shippedOrdersChart'));\n rgviz_shippedOrdersChart_data = response.getDataTable();\n rgviz_shippedOrdersChart_options = {\"is3D\":true,\"width\":\"100%\",\"height\":\"80%\",\"legend\":\"none\",\"chartArea\":{\"left\":70,\"top\":30,\"width\":\"85%\",\"height\":\"75%\"}};\n rgviz_shippedOrdersChart.draw(rgviz_shippedOrdersChart_data, rgviz_shippedOrdersChart_options);\n});\n}\ngoogle.setOnLoadCallback(rgviz_draw_shippedOrdersChart);\n</script>\n\n <div id=\"usersChart\"></div>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar rgviz_usersChart = null;\nvar rgviz_usersChart_data = null;\nfunction rgviz_draw_usersChart() {\n var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://stats.zurbanculture.fr/users/datasource');\n var q = 'select concat(month(`created_at`), \" \", year(`created_at`)), `seo`, `organique` where (`created_at` >= \"2012-04-23\" and `created_at` <= \"2013-04-24\" and `confirmed` = 1) group by concat(month(`created_at`), \" \", year(`created_at`)) order by `created_at` asc label concat(month(`created_at`), \" \", year(`created_at`)) \\'Month\\', `seo` \\'SEO\\', `organique` \\'Organique\\'';\n query.setQuery(q);\n query.send(function(response) {\n rgviz_usersChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('usersChart'));\n rgviz_usersChart_data = response.getDataTable();\n rgviz_usersChart_options = {\"is3D\":true,\"width\":\"100%\",\"height\":\"80%\",\"legend\":{\"position\":\"bottom\",\"textStyle\":{\"fontSize\":12}},\"chartArea\":{\"left\":70,\"top\":30,\"width\":\"85%\",\"height\":\"75%\"}};\n rgviz_usersChart.draw(rgviz_usersChart_data, rgviz_usersChart_options);\n});\n}\ngoogle.setOnLoadCallback(rgviz_draw_usersChart);\n</script>\n\n\n</div>\n</div>\n<footer class='footer'>\n<p>Zurban Culture v2.0 - Rails 3.2.13 (staging) / Ruby 1.9.3 patchlevel 327 2012-11-10 - /srv/www/jeansattitude/releases/20130423082652</p>\n</footer>\n</div>\n<script src=\"/assets/admin-ac2e83dde06736c3279cc5c973afd46a.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

Someone has an idea why the request fails and the body is not containing and array like it needs to be? Here you see my traceroute, it isn't clear for me what cause the problem because I don't see any trace of my application in it and I don't pass anything to this function from my application.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000009371f28>):
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:59:in `digest_body'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__965187821369700966__call__4271865895200548975__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.11) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.11) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.1.11) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.19) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

See also my issue I opened on the rack gem, but it seems not a issue from them. https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/548

SOLUTION:

This happened because of a custom middleware that was returning the body as a string, I wrapped this body in an array and problem was solved! Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like your app, or a piece of middleware between your app and `Rack::Etag`, is returning a string as the response body rather than something that responds to `each`. Have you added any middleware? (Returning a string as the response body used to bo okay in Ruby 1.8 and earlier, but the `each` method was removed from `String` in Ruby 1.9).

Comment: @matt Thanks! I used indeed a middleware to rewrite the path of my s3 assets, seems that it was written for ruby 1.8! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I inspected the body and it is a string with all the html code of my page in it. The data   type of this parameter should be an array.

Where is the `body` parameter coming from? What do you expect the elements of this array to be? It seems like this *may* be what you want:

```
def digest_body(body)
    parts = body.split("\n")
    string_body = parts.join
    digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(string_body) unless string_body.empty?
    [digest, parts]
end
```

Comment: It is the Rack gem that include this, not me. I edit the gem and put just body.inspect in it and saw that it was a string. Normaly it should be an array with a lot of stuff in it ( headers, ... ). Like I mentioned in my post, I don't call this explicit, it is called somewhere deeply in rails I think but can't find what cause this problem.